# Getting Bloodhound to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm implementing a typing suggestion functionality on my website using [Typeahead.js/Bloodhound](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js) but I can't get Bloodhound to work. Here is the code:

```
var indicator_commands = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(d.defaultInput);
    },        
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    prefetch: '/static/indicator.json',
});

console.log (indicator_commands.index.serialize());
indicator_commands.initialize();
console.log (indicator_commands.index.serialize());
```

Here is part of the indicator.json:

```
[
    {   "name": "sma",
        "fullname": "Smooth Moving Average",
        "parameter": "sma,period,applied_to_optional,#color_optional;",
        "defaultInput": "sma,14,close,#ababab;",
        "tokens" : ["sma,14,close,#ababab;"],
        "short_help": "",
        "long_help": "",
    },

    {   "name": "ema",
        "fullname": "Exponential Moving Average",
        "parameter": "ema,period,applied_to_optional,#color_optional;",
        "defaultInput": "ema,14,close,#ababab;",
        "tokens" : ["ema,14,close,#ababab;"],
        "short_help": "",
        "long_help": "",
    }
]
```

I was expecting some data in `indicator_commands` but it showed none. What do I need to change to get it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid.

You have a comma after the lest member of the object, ie. `"long_help" : "",`
that is messing up bloodhoubd, you have to remove that.

You should also beware that `indicator_commands.initialize();` will return
a `Promise` according to bloodhound docs, so you have no guarantee that it actually has been initialized on your second call to `serialize()`. Although the code as is with the JSON fixed worked for me, you should probably use the `Promise`:

```
indicator_commands.initialize().then(function(b) {
     console.log('Success');
     console.log(indicator_commands.index.serialize());
},
function(e) { console.log('Error'); } );
```